# What airfoil design does the MQ-9 Reaper UAV use?

Tags: airfoil, mq-9-reaper

What airfoil design does the MQ-9 Reaper UAV use?  Alternatively, what similar airfoil designs exist?

I'm running simulations for the effects of vortex generators for a school project and I would like to study the Reaper drones.

Comment: I'd suggest using gliders as they have a lot more published data, and even vortex generator studies in the open literature. Military aircraft and UAV's do not generally have data for the public eyes. If it's a school project, you'll be at safer grounds in publishing your results too.

Comment: Use the [GA(W)-1](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=ls417-il) as a replacement. It should not be too different and a lot of work on it has been published.

Comment: GA(W)-1 by no means at all close to GW series airfoils. GW series in intended to fly ~1-0.5 Million RN while GA(W) is intended to fly ~10 million. And operating CL range is also very different.

Answer (score 5):

The wing root of the General Atomics RQ-9 is the Drela GW-19/GW-25.

The wing tip airfoil is the Drela GW-27.

Because of their application, you will likely have difficulty finding study results of vortex generators used on that blended airfoil. There are papers, but I have only seen them in the DTIC library, and I do not recall the classification of them. However, the aircraft has been exported, so you may find some open literature on the airfoil, and the adaptations and optimization of it.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect such an old answer but do you remember where you got this information?

Answer (score 1):

Similar airfoil if you go higher Reynolds number is NLF 1015 and NASA LRN 1015.
One paper specifically investigated what you have suggested above is this.

AIAA-2003-0211
Enhanced Airfoil Design Incorporating Boundary Layer Mixing Devices
Michael Kerho and Brian Kramer

On the original airfoil design without vortex generators.

THE DESIGN. OF AN AIRFOIL. FOR. A HIGH-ALTITUDE,. LONG-ENDURANCE. REMOTELY. PILOTED. VEHICLE. N9 0- 12 545. Mark. D. Maughmer.