# What airfoil is used on the MQ-1B Predator's wing?

Tags: airfoil, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

There are lot of UAV's in todays world to be re worked on. The General Atomics series of UCAVs is quite remarkable. I have selected MQ-1B Predator UAV, for an geometric analysis project(undergraduate).
Though the wing dimensions including root and tip chord's length are found at https://mq-1predator.weebly.com/design-and-specifications.html and the rest performance specifications for it is available at https://www.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/104469/mq-1b-predator/.

Still it isn't mentioned anywhere at websites and in factsheet too, about its "Airfoil profile".
I have been trying to figure it out.

Can anyone please help me out to ascertain MQ-1B's airfoil profile?

Comment: Related: [What airfoil design does the MQ-9 Reaper UAV use?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45407/14897)

Comment: Look at this table: https://pdfhall.com/the-incomplete-guide-to-airfoil-usage-ulm_5b6dd1b0097c47783f8b45b8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MQ-1B uses three different airfoils: Drela GW-19, GW-25 and GW-27, created by Dr. Mark Drela (one of the creators of the XFOIL software) and proprietary to General Atomics.

> The airfoils used on the MQ-1B (Drela GW-19, GW-25, GW-27, created by Dr. Mark Drela) are proprietary material of General Atomics. Dr. Drela personally stated on a [hobbyist remote-control drone forum](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?1227417-Predator-Airfoil) that a scale model should use an SD7032 wing (similar shape to a NACA 3510), while the full-scale MQ-1B airfoils "...have LOTS of top surface camber."

["Fixed-Wing UAV Airframe Design and Validation", Bachelor's Thesis of Timothy Brown, University of Queensland](https://scholar.google.com/scholar_lookup?title=Fixed-Wing%20UAV%20Airframe%20Design%20and%20Validation)

Comment: BTW the quotes before your edit (directly from the thesis) are the correct ones, as the only bit being reproduced as said is the *have LOTS of top surface camber* bit ([permalink](https://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?p=15097078&postcount=34)).

Comment: Heh, I must have been wearing my glasses sideways. :)